# kernel size and stride value for fully convolutional network for semantic segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, computer-vision, tensorflow

I am not very clear about some technical details in implementing [Fully Convolutional Networks
for Semantic Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06211v1.pdf).  The paper discusses three models: fcn32, fcn16 and fcn18. According to this description, for fcn16, looks like the last deconvolutional layer has stride 16. But what is the stride for the skip layer from pool 4.
Similarly, for fcn8, looks like the last deconvolutional layer has stride 8. But what is the stride for the skip layer from pool3 and poo4?

In the [Tensorflow implementation of this model](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/tensorflow-fcn/blob/master/fcn8_vgg.py), author uses `stride=2` for all these skip level cases? Are there any justifications for this?

Moreover, for deconvolutional kernel, we also need to know the kernel size. The paper does not mention that. The above implementation using “kernel size = 4”, which can be found from the following definition, where ksize=4 is setup in defining the _upscore_layer.  What should be the criteria for setting up this kernel size.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fcn32` uses a stride of 32 because after `pool5` the spatial resolution is `2^5=32` times smaller, similarly `pool4` should use a stride of `2^4=16` and `pool3` should use a stride of `2^3=8`.

That tensorflow model first uses stride 2 to upsample `pool5` to the same size as `pool4`, then uses another stride 2 to upsample these two to be the same size as `pool3`, and finally upsamples these three all together with stride 8. So `pool5` gets enlarged `2*2*8=32` times, `pool4` gets enlarged `2*8=16` times and `pool3` `8` times, which is correct.

The reason of doing it this way instead of using strides of `8` `16` and `32` separately for each layer is to save the amount of computations. As in the end we are summing them together it's more efficient to sum before upsampling than after.

The kernel size seems more of a design choice, though it is not mentioned in the paper directly, the paper provides a link to their [Caffe implementation](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn8s-atonce/net.py#L60), which uses a kernel size of 4 for stride 2 layers.

Comment: Hi dontloo, thank you very much for the answer. Just for confirmation, when you talk about 2^5=32. Is that because the before pool5, each layer has one convolutional layer and one pooling layer(which down-sample the original image by stride=2 at each layer). Is that right? Thanks.

Comment: @user3125 right, I forgot to mention that.